# mdadm raid1 arrays different size on same size partitions

Tags: mdadm, software-raid

I just noticed something very odd. I have two systems with Ubuntu 18.04 Server. They are partitioned exactly the same down to the byte. I verified the partition sizes with `blockdev --getsize64`. However, the sizes of the md mirror devices on those partitions are different on both systems according to `blockdev --getsize64` and `mdadm --detail /dev/mdwhatever`. They both use the same metadata format (1.2 I think, the default) and were created with `mdadm --create /dev/mdfoo --level=mirror --raid-devices=2 /dev/sdfoo /dev/sdbar`. How is this possible?

Comment: Probably a different data offset. Check with `mdadm --examine` - mdadm picks some offset by default and those defaults changed over time. Also the data offset may change when doing any kind of raid conversions or grow operations.

Comment: @frostschutz It seems you are right, I recreated the older arrays and now they are the same size as the newer ones